# Show one post per author and order by custom field

Tags: functions

I display one post per author with function below and works fine, but is possible order by custom field?

```
<?php
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'author_groupby');
function author_groupby($groupby)
{
 global $wpdb;
 $author_groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author";
    if(preg_match("/$author_groupby/", $groupby)) {
    // grouping we need is already there
    return $groupby;
  }
  if(strlen(trim($groupby) == 0)) {
    // groupby was empty, use ours
    return $author_groupby;
  }
  return "$groupby, $author_groupby";
}
```

I've tried with code below but do not works:

```
...
$author_groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author 
AND pm.meta_key = 'KEY' 
ORDER BY pm.meta_value DESC Limit 0,1";
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in more detail? What is the result you want in human terms?

Answer (score 0):

You use a `AND` statement after a `GROUP BY` statement. That wont work.

Try altering the `WHERE` statement (`posts_where_paged` filter) to add the `AND pm.meta_key = 'KEY'` line.

Additionally you can use the `posts_orderby` filter to alter the `ORDER BY`.

**EDIT**

You can find some additional information [here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/posts_groupby?version=3.4&file=wp-includes/query.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is a `posts_orderby` filter that works like the `posts_groupby` filter you are already using. I don't see the point of trying to write the code since I don't know what your key is.

To make the orderby work you may need filters on `posts_fields` and/or `posts_joins` as well.

I don't know that your question is precise enough to give a better answer.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries

Comment: I would show one post per author and order by post meta value. 
Example:
(1) Post by author XXX with post meta 150
(2) Post by author YYY with post meta 100
(3) Post by author ZZZ with post meta 50
...